# Windows Service which I don't know if its even installed properly and working

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I'm currently working on a Service which allows me to format a certain file and then delete it.
My code looks good and should be working, but I cannot start my Service. Or better said I initialized a Logger in the onStart method and wrote something to my file like "Service Started" nothing more.
No Log-File, the file I want to format never gets touched nothing.

For reference purpose my code looks something like this:

```
      private FileSystemWatcher watcher;
        private string path = "C:\\"; // Pfad des Arbeitsverzeichnisses
        private string filter = "Kunden.csv"; // Name der Datei


        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .WriteTo.File("Log.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
                .CreateLogger();
            Log.Information("Der Dienst wurde erfolgreich gestartet.");
            // Konfiguration des FileSystemWatchers
            watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            watcher.Path = path;
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
            watcher.Filter = filter;

            Log.Information("Der watcher wurde erfolgreich initialisiert.");

            // Ereignisbehandlung für das Erstellen der Datei
            watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnCreated);
           
            // Beginnen der Überwachung
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            // Überprüfen, ob die Datei bereits vorhanden ist
            string filePath = Path.Combine(path, "test.txt");
            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                // Wenn die Datei vorhanden ist, verarbeite sie
                Log.Information("Das File ist bereits vorhanden.");
                ProcessFile(filePath);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
            watcher.Dispose();
        }

        private void OnCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Log.Information("Eine neue Datei wurde erzeugt.");
 
         // Do bunch of stuff..
            File.Delete("Kunden.csv");
        }
        
        private void ProcessFile(string path)
        {
         // Do bunch of Stuff..
        }    
  }
```

And my Programm.cs looks like this:

```
using Serilog;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DanLevelImporter
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Der Haupteinstiegspunkt für die Anwendung.
        /// </summary>
        static void Main()
        {
            Log.Information("Hi Service");
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
            {
                new Service1()
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }
    }
}
```

Could anyone help me to get this Service running?

Comment: What does "I cannot start my service" mean in particular? How have you configured your service to be run by Windows?

Comment: Check Event Viewer for errors in the Service.

Comment: I can start my Service and the Service is there when i wanna check it in the Services but nothing gets logged and no file gets formatted.

Comment: I try to install my Service with "sc create <ServiceName> binPath="Path" and then start it with sc start <ServiceName>

Comment: Did you try to use a full path for "Log.txt"?

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to know while working with windows services:

1. Default installation path is not `bin\Debug` folder, When you install a windows service it will be placed on `System32`, open `Start Menu` type `Services` in services window find your service and right-click on it and select `Properties`. you can see the `Path to executable`. You should know that when you use a relative path in I/O operations its related to this path.

[image]

2. The User who runs your `Windows Service` is not the `Current user` its, It's because of the nature of `Windows services` the name of the user is shown on `Log On As` column in `Services` window (there are some predefined users which are responsible to load your OS properly). So you may not have permission to write (or doing some modification) on specific `drive` or folders. I suggest you to use relative path to ensure that you can write there.
3. For debugging purposes, you can follow below pattern:

   ```
   // In your service file: 
   public void OnDebug()
   {
       OnStart(null);
   }

   protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
   {
       System.Threading.Thread mainThread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(MainMethod));
       mainThread.Start();

       #if DEBUG
       // Dont close my application 
       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
       #endif
   }

   public void MainMethod()
   {
       // Whatever you want.
   }
   ```

and in `program.cs`:

```
         static void Main()
         {
 #if DEBUG
             var service = new Service1();
             service.OnDebug();
 #else
                 ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
                 ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
                 {
                     new Service1()
                 };
                 ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
 #endif
         }
```

you can simply debug your application like `console applications` but you should remember the notes that I mentioned above.

There are several nuget packages that make you feel better while writing windows services for example [Simplify.WindowsServices](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Simplify.WindowsServices).